# Angular Material Sidenav Template?

Tags: angularjs, material-design

I'm trying to implement the Material Design's Sidenav. I've got it to work correctly, but I was wondering if I can add templates to it like the mdDialog templates so that I can view different information on it?

I also was wondering how to get the side animation to work as for me right now, it just appears and has a fading black overlay.

Thanks